# How do I change hosts file only for a snap app instead of changing my system hosts file?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, snap, hosts

I see every snap app (in /snap directory) have a etc directory and some of them have a hosts file.
Can I change it to prevent snap app connect to an address?

Comment: Related: [Hosts file for snap applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168284/hosts-file-for-snap-applications)