# Hosts file for snap applications

Tags: 18.04, snap, spotify, hosts

I installed spotify using snap. Now I wanted to change the hosts file to block ads. I used to change the global hosts file and it worked. But then I was installing spotify from the apt repository. I tried to change hosts again without any effect. Then I tried to change/create a hosts file in `/snap/spotify/current/etc`. But I got an error.

```
$ sudo touch hosts
[sudo] password for username: 
touch: cannot touch 'hosts': Read-only file system
```

Now I have three questions:

1. What if the file does not exist, which hosts file is valid?
2. If I need to create a hosts file exactly there, how do I solve the problem?
3. How else can this problem be solved?

Comment: Related: [How I change hosts file only for a snap app instead of changing my system hosts file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137582/how-i-change-hosts-file-only-for-a-snap-app-instead-of-changing-my-system-hosts)